# How to implement Custom Ribbon resizing in Excel 2007?

Tags: vsto, excel-2007, ribbon, ribbon-control

I'm working in a ribbon project for Excel 2007, using Visual Studio 2008 and VSTO, I'm trying to make my ribbon's groups collapse into galleries when I resize the Excel window, this is a functionality that the other tabs in the ribbon have (the tabs that come with Excel).

At first, I thought this wouldn't be that much difficult, I imagine that it would be like a property from the ribbon, but I have researched a lot about it and it seems that it is not that much easier.

I was looking at [this](http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/02/14/ribbon-step-by-step-part-4-exploring-other-controls.aspx) article, there is a post from a guy called "Mike McGavin", he is asking for the same thing that I'm, and the guy that answer his question tells him that auto resize is not current functionality on custom groups/controls.

Now, that post is 1.5 years old...so I'm hoping something new has been out there, maybe some of you know something about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in 2010. Scroll down to Custom Group Auto-Scaling section.
http://blogs.technet.com/office2010/archive/2009/11/03/ui-extensibility-in-office-2010.aspx